# jquery ui dialog will not "close"

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I have a jquery dialog that I want to make JIT (Just in Time) this, to me, is by far the most elegant way of working, but I have spent about 2 days solid on this error and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

I know it should work because the X click in the corner works beautifully

So. Can you a) help me fix this or b) tell me how to bind the Cancel button to the click event of the X (I have used this trick before when there has been such issues, but there is no id on this control that I can find, and now obvious way (that I know how to find) to browse the hierarchy using parents().

```
 $(function() {
     var popUrl = 'pop.php?jscriptpopup=true';
     $("#button").click( function () { 
         JQueryDialog(popUrl); 
         return false;
     });        
 });

var dialog;  //<--added in desperation

function JQueryDialog(url){

    $("#dialog").remove();

    $("body").append("<div id='dialog'></div>"); 

    dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 770,
        height: 470,
        context: that,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel" : function (){
                $(dialog).("close");    //<--this will not work
                                    //$(this).dialog("close"); <<-- hopeless
                                    //$("#dialog").dialog("close"); <<-- hopeless
                                    //$("#dialog").remove(); <<-- hopeless
            }
        }
    });     

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');        
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after doing this to death, the moment I posted I stumbled upon it within seconds - often the way

this works.. no idea why

```
function JQueryDialog(url){

    $("#dialog").remove();

    $("body").append("<div id='dialog'></div>"); 

    that = $("#dialog");

    dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 770,
        height: 470,
        context: that,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel" : function (){
                that.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });     

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');        
    });     
}
```

Comment: According to the jquery UI docs `$(this).dialog("close")` should work inside the Cancel. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: yes I know it should work but I strongly suspect that this an override in bubble accident caused by a after-include-lib-some.js (I doubt it, I commented all them out one by one as a test) or a bug (I used 3 or 4 version of jQuery and they all seem to suffer it) i.e. bug as a derivation of the fact that I added the div to the DOM

Comment: I have had a ponder and it *must* be because the $('#dialog') is actually replaced with some behind the scenes logic so that there are now 2: $('#the-old-dialog-div-now-replaced-that-actions-exist-in') and a "let me handle this" $('#dialog') that is actually a replacement to nestle within.. and somehow a prepare event that the *replacement* $('#dialog') uses isn't paired properly to become to $(this) when you append the div the way I do... therefore (if my guess here is correct) the "that" works because it's part of the *shell* div's event